How to get rid of the expansion/collapse buttons from all columns starting from the second column in pivot tables(i just need it in the first column)
image
please check the image above. i want to get rid of the (-) buttons from col 2, col 3 and starttime. is that possible?
I know it is possible if we have decimal or integer based columns, we can use them in the values section and that does the trick.. but what if we have text and date format columns?
